# Update table using combination of 2 fields without using primary key

Tags: mysql, cakephp

Im trying to convert this direct update query into cake's way of updating.

```
$this->Test->query("UPDATE tests SET rating=3 WHERE goal_id=1 AND employee_id=28");
```

Normally when we update we set the id and then save, right?

```
$this->id = 1;
$this->Test->save($data);
```

But here im making use of combination of (goal_id+employee_id) to identify the rows. So how can i do an update on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `updateAll()`, you just happen to be updating 1 record rather than the many records that the name of the method would suggest.

```
Model::updateAll(array $fields, array $conditions)
```

So, for your test you'd use:

```
$this->Test->updateAll(
    array('rating' => 3),
    array('goal_id' => 1, 'employee_id' => 28)
);
```